# Import xml key value pair to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have the XML data below that represents one row but can't seem to get this imported into sql server without completely rewriting the xml file to look like the second block of code at the very bottom. I have thousands of small xml files in the first format I need to start processing and importing into a sql table. Ideally if I don't use some custom scripting to rewrite the xml I'm thinking I could import into a temp table and use pivot or transposing to get the attributes into cells in a row.

```
<ping>
<feed Scale="4.0" resolution="67.58859099656746">
<beta name="my_misc_beta" totalRecords="1">
<row>
<column>
 <key>CUSTOMER ID</key>
 <value>123456</value>
 </column>
<column>
 <key>CUSTOMER NAME</key>
 <value>Johnys Bike Shop</value>
 </column>
<column>
 <key>REGION NAME</key>
 <value>Cool Area</value>
 </column>
<column>
 <key>CUSTOMER CATEGORY</key>
 <value>Bike Shop</value>
 </column>
<column>
 <key>CUSTOMER DESCRIPTION</key>
 <value>coolest bike shop</value>
 </column>
<column>
 <key>CUSTOMER STATUS</key>
 <value>Current</value>
 </column>
<column>
 <key>CUSTOMER CONTACT</key>
 <value>johnny@bikeshop.net</value>
 </column>
 </row>
 </beta>
 </feed>
 </ping>
```

This xml below easily imports into sql server using ssis and looping through the directory. But I had to hand rewrite this by hand for testing. Is there a way with maybe c# or another language to take the inside text and write them to element tags etc in ssis. Compare the two xml docs and you'll see that the above code will not import diectly to a row.

```
<ping>
<feed Scale="4.0" resolution="67.58859099656746">
<beta name="my_misc_beta" totalRecords="1">
<row>
<column>
 <CUSTOMER_ID>123456</CUSTOMER_ID>
 <CUSTOMER_NAME>Johnys Pedal Shop</CUSTOMER_NAME>
 <REGION_NAME>Cool Area</REGION_NAME>
 <CUSTOMER_CATEGORY>Bike Shop</CUSTOMER_CATEGORY>
 <CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION>coolest bike shop</CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION>
 <CUSTOMER_STATUS>Current</CUSTOMER_STATUS>
 <CUSTOMER_CONTACT>johnny@bikeshop.net</CUSTOMER_CONTACT>
 </column>
 </row>
 </beta>
 </feed>
 </ping>
```

Comment: Will the column names be changing often?

Comment: @RaySülzer no the columns will not change at all if they do I would need to change the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about what XML capabilities there are in SSIS but you can do what you want using a regular query.

First you need to shred the XML on the `row` node using [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to get one row in the resul for each `row` in the XML.

Then you use [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract the column value you want. You could fetch the values by `column` number but it is safer to check the `key` value in a predicate before fetching the value.

```
select T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "CUSTOMER ID"]/value/text())[1]', 'int') as CustomerID,
       T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "CUSTOMER NAME"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomerName,
       T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "REGION NAME"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as RegionName,
       T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "CUSTOMER CATEGORY"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomerCategory,
       T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "CUSTOMER DESCRIPTION"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomerDescription,
       T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "CUSTOMER STATUS"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomerStatus,
       T.X.value('(column[key/text() = "CUSTOMER CONTACT"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomerContact
from @XML.nodes('/ping/feed/beta/row') as T(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17368)

Comment: @ Mikael Eriksson Thanks I wasn't sure how much I could do with pure sql. This is a big help, I should be able to run this within a SSIS package. I have the table created I'll just need to work on inserting the values with each shred of a new xml document.